# Has the way Joomla Overrides works changed?

Tags: overrides, template-override

When I create an overide in Joomla using the create override button it creates an override like this:

```
blog_item-29-09-2021
```

but then Joomla complains that it wants the `_item` at the end like this

```
blog-29-09-2021_item
```

Either way is fine by me but Joomla is creating them in a certain way which confuses me.

Or is there some other way I should understand this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you override the blog view, the entry point to that view is the `blog.php` file. But inside that file, a call to a `blog_item.php` exists `$this->loadTemplate('item');`. That is why the override look for `_item.php`.

Comment: But then the way Joomla creates the overrides is incorrect right?

Comment: Why you think is incorrect? if you use the same Blog layout, Joomla first will look for a blog.php file in your HTML folder before use the default location inside the component

Comment: I think it's incorrect because if you press the "create overrides" button it creates like `blog_item-29-09-2021`